# Facebook tabs - all visible?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am wondering why Coca Cola could have all of their tabs visible by default:
http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_316829601660434

What I mean is in the left column where all their tabs are listed, you don't have to press "See more" to see all of them. On my page only five tabs are visible by default and you have to press the "See more"-button to see the rest of them.

I wonder how it is possible to have like Coca Cola.

Could it possibly be because they are such a great company and have some kind of special permissions or something?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because your URL directly points to an app (tab) that is usually in the "See More" section. If you try the following, you won't see all tabs:

- http://www.facebook.com/cocacola: There's the "See more" button.
- [http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_132920893413852](http://www.facebook.com/cocacola): There's also the "See more" button, beause the tab is above the hidden ones.